# read_csv: Multiple Header Rows. Single header row has duplicates within it, but no column is duplicated when both header rows considered

Tags: python, pandas

I need to read a particular csv file into a Pandas data frame.  The file has 2 header rows. Each header row contains duplicate entries, but when all header rows are considered together, no column multi header is a duplicate of any other column.  The 1st column should be the vertical index of the data frame.  The resulting data frame will be used to search for a 3-part tuple, which is the intersection of the row index, and the column containing matching data in both header row 1 and header row 2.

Sample csv file:

```
Exp,2023-09-22,2023-09-22,2023-09-29,2023-10-06,2023-10-13
Code,A,B,A,A,A
Item,,,,,
260,1,8,17,31,42
270,2,9,18,32,43
280,3,10,19,33,44
290,4,11,20,34,45
300,5,12,21,35,46
```

EXP is header row 1.
Code is header row 2.
Item is the name of the items which should be the row index of the data frame.

My attempts so far have resulted in Pandas mangling any header row 1 date value that is a duplicate of any other header row 1 date value.  It appends a ".1" to such a duplicate date.  That is unwanted behavior.  Passing "mangle_dupe_cols=False" to the function results in a Future Warning, which precludes me from using that method to stop the mangling behavior of the function.  On other attempts, read_csv() simply discards any column in which header row 1 date value is a duplicate of any other header row 1 date value.  That is also unwanted behavior.  This question specifically relates to the correct way to read the file into a data frame structure.  But anyone with depth on this specific issue is asked to consider the following as well:

The data frame, once properly read in, will be used to search for the value at the intersection of all three indices.  For example, if I want the value at this intersection: (280, 2023-09-22, B) the search should return integer 10.  If I were to search for (280, 2023-09-22, A), the correct return value would be integer 3.

Header row 1 is a datetime.date type. After accomplishing this basic search, an additional task will be to interpolate the return value for those occasions where a target date is passed that lies between any of the available choices in header row 1. Such an interpolation will then depend on the header row 2 variable to determine which columns should be selected for the subsequent interpolation. If you have ideas about this, please include them in your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post includes many questions in one. To answer the first one, you'll probably receive many suggestions for the shape unless you give an explicit one.

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", header=[0, 1], index_col=0).iloc[1:]
```

Output :

```
print(df)

Exp  2023-09-22     2023-09-29 2023-10-06 2023-10-13
Code          A   B          A          A          A
Item                                                
270           2   9         18         32         43
280           3  10         19         33         44
290           4  11         20         34         45
300           5  12         21         35         46
```

To ask for a specific value, you can use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) or [`at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) :

```
df.loc[280, ("2023-09-22", "B")] # gives 10
df.loc[280, ("2023-09-22", "A")] # gives 3
```

Comment: Timeless, you are incredible.  I've been working on this problem for more than a week, and even Chat GPT and Claude AI could not make progress with it.  Thank you for taking the time to solve this for me.