# Python Pandas Multi-Index. Count the number of multi-index sub-headings for a given multi-index main heading

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I need to count the number of multi-index sub-headings for a given multi-index main heading.

This question is related to my previous question here:  [read_csv: Multiple Header Rows. Single header row has duplicates within it, but no column is duplicated when both header rows considered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77158600/read-csv-multiple-header-rows-single-header-row-has-duplicates-within-it-but/77158722)
If that link doesn't pass, the search term on stackoverflow would be: "read_csv: Multiple Header Rows. Single header row has duplicates within it, but no column is duplicated when both header rows considered"

Using the same sample csv file:

#### Sample csv file:

```
Exp,2023-09-22,2023-09-22,2023-09-29,2023-10-06,2023-10-13  
Code,A,B,A,A,A  
Item,,,,,  
260,1,8,17,31,42  
270,2,9,18,32,43  
280,3,10,19,33,44  
290,4,11,20,34,45  
300,5,12,21,35,46
```

##### And reading the csv into a data frame like this:

#### Gives Output:

```
print(df)

Exp  2023-09-22     2023-09-29 2023-10-06 2023-10-13
Code          A   B          A          A          A
Item                                                
270           2   9         18         32         43
280           3  10         19         33         44
290           4  11         20         34         45
300           5  12         21         35         46
```

Question:  How do I count the number of "Code" entries for a given Exp heading?
For example:
How many Code entries are listed for Exp '2023-09-22'?  Answer: 2 (they are 'A' and 'B')
How many Code entries are listed for Exp '2023-10-13'?  Answer: 1

Any help coding up this query is greatly appreciated.

I've tried all kinds of combinations of len(df.columns[col_idx]) and other iterations, but nothing is getting me there.  As for acceptable solution approaches, I'd run with either a count, such as int 2 or int 1, or a list of the names or values (or whatever they are deemed to be) that I could subsequently count.  In all cases, the Codes will consist of either "A" or "B", or both ["A"&"B"].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code**

groupby + size (by level 0 of columns)

```
df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).size()
```

output:

```
Exp
2023-09-22      2
2023-09-29      1
2023-10-06      1
2023-10-13      1
```

If your Code list is not unique (*for example, if there are A, A, B under 2023-09-22 and you want to return 2*), use following code.

```
df.droplevel(level=-1, axis=1).columns.to_frame(index=False).groupby('Exp')['Code'].nunique()
```

Comment: Thank you, Panda Kim.  Your answer covered every aspect of my question and the even larger issues I was having that were not included with the question.  Much appreciated.